# How to test cookies.permanent.signed in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jrubyonrails

I have a action in some controller that set some value in a permanent signed cookie like this:

```
def some_action
    cookies.permanent.signed[:cookie_name] = "somevalue"
end
```

And in some functional test, I'm trying to test if the cookie was set correctly suing this:

```
test "test cookies" do
    assert_equal "somevalue", cookies.permanent.signed[:cookie_name]
end
```

However, when I run the test, I got the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `permanent' for #
```

If I try only:

```
test "test cookies" do
    assert_equal "somevalue", cookies.signed[:cookie_name]
end
```

I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `signed' for #
```

How to test signed cookies in Rails 3?

Answer (score 18):

I came across this question while Googling for a solution to a similar issue, so I'll post here. I was hoping to set a signed cookie in Rspec before testing a controller action. The following worked:

```
jar = ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar.build(@request)
jar.signed[:some_key] = "some value"
@request.cookies['some_key'] = jar[:some_key]
get :show ...
```

Note that the following didn't work:

```
# didn't work; the controller didn't see the signed cookie
@request.cookie_jar.signed[:some_key] = "some value"
get :show ...
```

Comment: Just ran across this and it solve my problem perfectly, but as an important addendum, I had to change:

@request.cookies[:some_key]

to:

@request.cookies["some_key"]

Comment: Great balexand. I wish you I could give you 10 thumbs-ups.

Comment: @Atiaxi, using Rails 3.2.12 and I could use the symbol to access the @request.cookies[:some_key] = jar[:some_key]

Comment: the original question was about looking into the response cookies. not the request cookies.

Comment: Rspec explains Strings vs Symbols when referencing cookies here: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/cookies

Answer (score 8):

In rails 3's ActionControlller::TestCase, you can set signed permanent cookies in the request object like so -

```
 @request.cookies.permanent.signed[:foo] = "bar"
```

And the returned signed cookies from an action taken in a controller can be tested by doing this

```
 test "do something" do
     get :index # or whatever
     jar = @request.cookie_jar
     jar.signed[:foo] = "bar"
     assert_equal jar[:foo], @response.cookies['foo'] #should both be some enc of 'bar'
 end
```

Note that we need to set signed cookie `jar.signed[:foo]`, but read unsigned cookie `jar[:foo]`. Only then we get the encrypted value of cookie, needed for comparison in `assert_equal`.

Comment: Awesome! I'm just using: `@request.cookie_jar.signed[:foo] = 'bar'`

Answer (score 7):

After looking at the Rails code that handles this I created a test helper for this:

```
  def cookies_signed(name, opts={})
    verifier = ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier.new(request.env["action_dispatch.secret_token".freeze])
    if opts[:value]
      @request.cookies[name] = verifier.generate(opts[:value])
    else
      verifier.verify(cookies[name])
    end
  end
```

Add this to test_help.rb, then you can set a signed cookie with:

```
cookies_signed(:foo, :value => 'bar')
```

And read it with:

```
cookies_signed(:foo)
```

A bit hackish maybe, but it does the job for me.

Comment: Nicely done, I've renamed the method to #signed_cookie, and slapped it  into a module for mixing into controller specs. [See this gist](https://gist.github.com/2694930) for a reference

Answer (score 2):

The problem (at least on the surface) is that in the context of a functional test (ActionController::TestCase), the "cookies" object is a Hash, whereas when you work with the controllers, it's a ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar object.  So we need to convert it to a CookieJar object so that we can use the "signed" method on it to convert it to a SignedCookieJar.

You can put the following into your functional tests (after a get request) to convert cookies from a Hash to a CookieJar object

```
@request.cookies.merge!(cookies)
cookies = ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar.build(@request)
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I'm using Test unit. I don't understand how to use your 2-liner. I tried different permutations but nothing worked. Can you please give a more thorough example on how to use this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem also appears to be your tests.

Here is some code and tests I used to TDD the situation where you want to set a cookie's value from passing a params value into a view.

Functional Test:

```
test "reference get set in cookie when visiting the site" do
  get :index, {:reference => "121212"}
  refute_nil cookies["reference"]
end
```

SomeController:

```
before_filter :get_reference_code
```

ApplicationController:

```
def get_reference_code
  cookies.signed[:reference] ||= params[:reference]
end
```

Notice that the refute_nil line, the cookies is a string... that is one thing that also made this test not pass, was putting a symbol in `cookies[:reference]` the test did not like that, so i didn't do that.